# Authenticating to MS Graph without user interaction (Rust)

Tags: rust, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Java application using the Microsoft Graph SDK to read from Azure AD. I am supposed to translate that application to Rust. In Java, i use code similar to this:

```java
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.identity.TokenCachePersistenceOptions;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

import java.util.List;

public class GraphSdkClient {
    public static void testApplicationClient() {
        TokenCachePersistenceOptions options = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions()
          .setName("ILM-Demo")
          .setUnencryptedStorageAllowed(false);

        ClientSecretCredentialBuilder builder = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
          .clientId("<MyClientId>")
          .tenantId("<MyTenantId>")
          .clientSecret("<MyClientSecret>")
          .tokenCachePersistenceOptions(options);

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider provider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
          List.of("Calendars.Read", "Calendars.ReadBasic.All"),
          builder.build()
        );

        GraphServiceClient<?> client = GraphServiceClient
          .builder()
          .authenticationProvider(provider)
          .buildClient();

        client.me().calendar().calendarView().buildRequest().get();
  }
}
```

It authenticates as an application, using only the client secret. The permission was given half a year ago and as long as the three values from the ClientSecretCredentialBuilder are correct, it works perfectly fine. Now i tried using a similar conecpt in Rust, taken from the graph-rs-sdk crate:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use graph_rs_sdk::oauth::OAuth;
    use warp::Filter;
    use crate::{CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_ID};
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    #[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    pub struct ClientCredentialsResponse {
        admin_consent: bool,
        tenant: String,
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn ut_client_credentials() {
        let query = warp::query::<ClientCredentialsResponse>()
            .map(Some)
            .or_else(|_| async {
                Ok::<(Option<ClientCredentialsResponse>,), std::convert::Infallible>((None,))
            });

        let routes = warp::get()
            .and(warp::path("redirect"))
            .and(query)
            .and_then(handle_redirect);

        // Get the oauth client and request a browser sign in
        let mut oauth = get_oauth_client();
        let mut request = oauth.build_async().client_credentials();
        request.browser_authorization().open().unwrap();

        warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8300)).await;
    }

    async fn handle_redirect(client_credential_option: Option<ClientCredentialsResponse>)
        -> Result<Box<dyn warp::Reply>, warp::Rejection> {
        match client_credential_option {
            Some(client_credential_response) => {
                // Print out for debugging purposes.
                println!("{:#?}", client_credential_response);

                // Request an access token.
                request_access_token().await;

                // Generic login page response.
                Ok(Box::new(
                    "Successfully Logged In! You can close your browser.",
                ))
            }
            None => Err(warp::reject()),
        }
    }

    async fn request_access_token() {
        let mut oauth = get_oauth_client();
        let mut request = oauth.build_async().client_credentials();
        let access_token = request.access_token().send().await.unwrap();

        println!("{:#?}", access_token);
        oauth.access_token(access_token);
    }

    fn get_oauth_client() -> OAuth {
        let mut oauth = OAuth::new();
        oauth
            .client_id(CLIENT_ID)
            .client_secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .tenant_id(TENANT_ID)
            .add_scope("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Invite.All")
            .redirect_uri("http://localhost:8300/redirect")
            // .authorize_url("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent")
            .access_token_url("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
        oauth
    }
}
```

Note that i commented out the authorize url. If this url exits, a browser window opens, requesting an admin to log in. This must not happen. When it is commented out, it sends the request directly to `<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` instead of `<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/adminconsent`, which is what i want, it instead complains: `AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'scope'.`. The scope is given though.

I already tried fiddling with urls for hours and also tried every other authentication concept in the crate, but it doesn't seem to work without interaction, which is not possible in my use case. Does someone know how to achieve that? (All permissions are granted as application permissions, not deligated)

Edit request: Please create and add the tag "graph-rs-sdk". I cannot create it myself but knowing the crate being used would be useful.

Comment: If you are using application permissions then `scope` must be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and you must add `grant_type` with value `client_credentials`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request

Comment: @user2250152 I think that clue will come in handy later on, but in itself it unfortunately doesn't change the behaviour i experience. If you get the unit test running with that snippet, please provide the entire unit test in an answer. Thank you ^^